# I have error on checkout page

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1

I have error on checkout page (see the image) .
Continue button is not working. Any luck ? [image]

Comment: do you have any custom theme / checkout extension installed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question i think you uploaded a google script (maybe review script ) , and the way you added the values blocks the current page for proceeding. Use this for delivery country :

```
 "delivery_country": "<?php echo $googleRatingData['delivery_country'] ?>",
```

For the delivery date :

```
 "estimated_delivery_date": "<?php echo $deliveryDate=Date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+12 days")); ?>",
```

Update the date as you want.

If this doesnt work for you , paste the full script here (without the mercant id ) so we can debug.