# Continue button not working on checkout magento 1

Tags: checkout, magento-1

On my checkout continue button not working in the first step.Although i enter all required values but button not going to next step.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please check javascript error, There might be any javascript conflict. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

This is Duplicate of [I have error on checkout page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/246776/i-have-error-on-checkout-page) . Anyway try to Ship to different address because you have required fields there unfilled.

Comment: I have edit my question.Actualy its regarding continue button.Other issues are solved.